Solving the Poisson equation
I am an undergraduate student, in this semester I am taking the course of partial differential equations.
So reading about Poisson equation by Evan's classic book for pdes, i have some questions:
Assume the Poisson equation $\Delta u=f$ with no boundary conditions,maybe in all $\mathbb{R}^n$.
If we change the properties of f how are we able to ensure that there exist a solution?
Assume that f is bounded and integrable in Gilbarg-Trundiger book for elliptic pde i found a statement that say's(lemma 4.1)
"Let f be bounded and integrable then the Newtonian potential of f , say w is in $C^1$"
How is this related to the answer of existence of solution?
Are we talking about classic or weak solutions?

The point is, if $f$ is integrable and bounded, Poisson's equation will have a solution , which can be given explicitly by $u=\Phi\ast f$.

Why is this true?  Is there any reference for this?

Presumably, it's in the Gilbarg-Trudinger book that you mentioned. Keep reading!

Thanks for the answer, i will search more and i will update the question

@K.defaoite Integrability and boundedness are enough for uniqueness, however, not for a well-posed solution. The right-hand-side $f$ cannot be choosen arbitrarily, since you have to fullfill an extra compatibility condition. Otherwise the solution would be non-sense (from a physical point of view).

@ConvexHull Please elaborate on this in an answer if possible.

The Poisson equation with à priori optional boundary condtions can be written as
\begin{align}
\Delta u(\mathbf x) &= f(\mathbf x),\qquad \mathbf x\in\Omega,\\[0.3em]
u(\mathbf x) &= g(\mathbf x),\qquad \mathbf x\in\partial\Omega_g,\\
\frac{\partial u(\mathbf x)}{\partial\mathbf n} &= h(\mathbf x),\qquad \mathbf x\in\partial\Omega_h.
\end{align}
A well posed solution has to fullfill the divergence theorem
\begin{align}
\int_\Omega f(\mathbf x)\,dV = \int_\Omega \operatorname{div}\nabla u(\mathbf x) \,dV = \oint_{\partial\Omega}\nabla u(\mathbf x)\cdot \mathbf n(\mathbf x)\,dS = \oint_{\partial\Omega} h(\mathbf x)\,dS,
\end{align}
which constrains the choice of $f(\mathbf x)$ with an implicit dependency on $h(\mathbf x)$.
